# Change height of row in GridView builder to fixed height

Tags: flutter, dart

I've noticed that GridView makes each child a square.. Is there any way to adjust height of each child which means entire row of GridView row in GridView.builder?

In this example I want to have each input next to each other.

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [
  {'description': 'des1'},
  {'description': 'des2'},
  {'description': 'des3'},
  {'description': 'des4'},
  {'description': 'des5'},
  {'description': 'des6'}
];

class _MaterialScreenState extends State<MaterialScreen> {
  String text = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(text),
        GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: list.length,
            gridDelegate:
                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 5),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return TextFormField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onTap: () => setState(() {
                  text = list[index]['description'];
                }),
                decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
              );
            }),
      ],
    ));
```

Problem:

[image]

Reason:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
  maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
  childAspectRatio: 3,
),
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: hmm... I guess that would work even when I wanted to have fixed number of items in one row this is so far the best workaround

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can use "childAspectRatio".

```
gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
  crossAxisCount: 5,
  childAspectRatio: 2,
),
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Yes.. but that doesn't make it fixed... does it? try to rotate the display